# Can't `brew link` an unlinked keg

Tags: node.js, homebrew

```
$: which node
$: node
-bash: node: command not found
$: brew install node
Error: node-0.6.18 already installed
$: brew doctor
Error: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built.

node

$: brew link node
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.6.5
$: brew uninstall node
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.6.5
$: brew install node
Error: node-0.6.18 already installed
```

How do I get my node back on track??

Comment: What does `brew doctor` says? If nothig helpful, you should consider [sending bug report](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Reporting-Bugs).

Comment: Error: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built.

    geos
    node
    postgis
    proj

Comment: For anyone else experiencing this problem, I think this is worth looking at too: [Error: The 'brew link' step did not complete successfully](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12607155/320399)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I was able to relink the correct version of node by running:

```
brew cleanup
brew link node
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```

Comment: I had to run the uninstall as sudo for some reason. But thanks, this worked.

Comment: Not helped. "brew link node" Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node

Comment: @AamirAfridi doesn't work. after run this command and run `brew uninstall node` this error occurred again

Comment: if you are like me and need to switch between node versions. simply install them and then switch with `brew link node@4` or `brew link node@6`

Answer (score 8):

I was getting:

```
$ brew link node
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node
$ brew link node@8
Warning: node@8 is keg-only and must be linked with --force
```

That command helped to get everything working again:

```
brew link --overwrite --force node@8
```

Comment: Thanks! 

I could solve a similar unlink error for gcc 
```% brew unlink gcc```
```Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc``` by using ```% brew unlink gcc@12```

Answer (score 0):

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally had to work some sudo chmod magic for node files that were not writable. Brew didn't take care of them by default even after --force was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you explain what this code does and why it is the answer to the question?

Comment: when you do the 'brew link node ' commande  you have to tap this command before to tell him where the node path is !

Answer (score 0):

I puzzled over this for a long time. Nothing worked.
I'm using macOS.

In a terminal, execute the following command to get nvm setup with appropriate node.js settings (for further details on what the script does read this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh):

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | zsh

Restart your terminal and run the following:

nvm -v
You should see a version.

Now let's install node:

nvm install 14.15
When the installation is finished, run:

node -v

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ruby. I wanted to uninstall it. Here is the fix that worked for me

```
brew install ruby
```

Then

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then When I tried uninstall it worked.

```
brew uninstall ruby
```

So you can do the same by replacing ruby with node. Then install it again and it will be fixed.