# Can no longer use npm command after trying to update

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I was trying to install yeoman but it threw an error regarding self signed certificates.

I looked this up and I found out I had to upgrade node.

Upgrading node however threw this: (forgot to use sudo with it...)

```
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  npm@1.4.4 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
```

After this I couldn't use npm anymore. It couldn't be found:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Trying to reinstall with brew:

```
It appears you already have npm installed at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Tells me to npm uninstall but I can't use npm anymore.

The error message is more detailed but I think the part about "unlinking" is the main thing. How do I go about linking it back up and also why was such a weird error thrown?

EDIT: also ran `npm config set ca ""` before trying to update node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found some links with similar errors and all with different solutions:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4099

[Error: The 'brew link' step did not complete successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155/error-the-brew-link-step-did-not-complete-successfully)

[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

The answer for the third one helped most I think, specifically:

*go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules*

Comment: Follow your links I could solve it, thanks. The command that works for me was:

sudo curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

Comment: And once you've done that, reload your bash session. Didn't work without it for me on my Vagrant box

Answer (score 27):

I installed using brew
after: brew install node

```
sudo brew postinstall node
```

Comment: I get an error telling me how I shouldn't run brew as root, and it just "cowardly" refuses to do so.

Answer (score 2):

sudo brew postinstall command works for me. This issue is caused if you try to update a core NPM package without using the sudo command