# Qmake installed but not linked - Using Brew - Mac

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, qmake

I have installed Qmake using brew.

```
brew install qt
```

The results which the terminal brings is:

```
Warning: qt-4.8.6 already installed, it's just not linked
```

This is a problem with brew to install correct the things? because I am having the same "not linked" problem with PostgreSQL.

Thks

> **I found the problem:** 
>   The Brew can't write to the folder /usr/local/lib/ 
>   
>   So I used the command: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib` 
>   
> I found a similar error here: [Brew doctor says: "Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable)
>   
>   But this problem was with another folder permission.

Comment: I found the problem:
The Brew can't write to the folder

    /usr/local/lib/

So I used the command:

    sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib

I found a similar error here:
[Brew doctor says: “Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.”][1]
But this problem was with another folder permission.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Brew can't write to the folder

```
/usr/local/lib/
```

So I used the command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib
```

After need uninstall and install qt again. (If you run reinstall the problem will continuous)

```
brew uninstall qt

brew install qt
```

I found a similar error here:
[Brew doctor says: “Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable)
But this problem was with another folder permission.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
brew link qt
```

Which should tell brew to link the package.

If that doesn't work, someone else had a similar problem here: [Error: The 'brew link' step did not complete successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155/error-the-brew-link-step-did-not-complete-successfully)