# npm isn't building when I run brew install node

Tags: node.js, path, npm, installation, homebrew

When running brew install node I'm not able to get npm to build. Here's the end of the node install I'm getting...

```
==> /usr/local/bin/npm install --global npm@latest --prefix /usr/local
--global
npm@latest
--prefix
/usr/local

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Summary
 /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32: 1678 files, 19M
```

Nothing doing when run brew postinstall node.

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following :

```
$ brew uninstall node
$ rm -r ~/.npm
$ brew install node
```

Comment: Hey Kilroy, that didn't get rid of the problem either.

Comment: I've seen a ~similar issue beeing resolved here http://forums.webhook.com/t/cant-get-node-to-install-on-latest-osx-mavericks-resolved/109. Hopefully that might help a bit.

Comment: I worked through that and was able to remove these errors: `make[1]: *** [node_modules/.bin/ronn] Error 3
make: *** [man/man3/npm-bin.3] Error 2` but I'm still getting `Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using brew postinstall node`

Comment: Did you give a look at that question? It might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155/error-the-brew-link-step-did-not-complete-successfully

Comment: I did have a look at that... I'm actually just clean installing now, so I should be good. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ha, probably sounds like the best option. Good luck!