# Node installation errors

Tags: node.js, appium

I faced next errors while make a preparation for installing Appium on my OS X machine. Unfortunately I installed it first with root-access by mistake but remove it

```
nb-user:npm user$ brew install node
Warning: node-0.12.0_1 already installed


npm install -g appium  # get appium
```

in results

```
 nb-user:~ user$ npm install -g appium
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/kad/.npm/appium/1.3.6/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/npm-debug.log
```

Install again under root user ( node versions errors )

```
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.4"})
```

appium not works under root :(

how can I completely remove node and appium(root and local user) in order to install it again without any  errors ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155/error-the-brew-link-step-did-not-complete-successfully I also used some advices but no way out :(

Answer (score 0):

this would help [Uninstall NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) or generalized way [`npm uninstall <package-name>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall)

Comment: Do a `npm update -g` and try again if it dint wornk do this, You can probably try deleting the node and appium folders inside AppData http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28928/what-is-the-osx-equivalent-to-windows-appdata-folder , i work on win8 so use that link

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Everything,
First install brew, then install npm from brew and then install appium from node.
i followed this in linux, it will help in mac too

http://install-appium-on-linux.blogspot.com/2015/01/install-ruby-sudo-apt-get-install-build.html