# Hiccup installing Node.js and NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I'm installing Node.js and NPM, so I used Homebrew to do so. I tried npm -v and node -v and they say:

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

So I tried reinstalling, and I get this:

```
MacBook-Pro:5.0.0 User$ brew install node
Warning: node-5.0.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155/error-the-brew-link-step-did-not-complete-successfully

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the environment variables，https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726962.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Mac OS X 10.11.