# error importing igraph in

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to install igraph but getting issue. I tried following various stack overflow links but couldn't get it right.

```
brew install igraph

==> Installing igraph from homebrew/science
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/igraph-0.7.1_3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: Library/Caches/Homebrew/igraph-0.7.1_3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring igraph-0.7.1_3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink lib/libigraph.0.dylib
Target /usr/local/lib/libigraph.0.dylib
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/lib/libigraph.0.dylib'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite igraph

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run igraph

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/lib/libigraph.0.dylib
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1_3: 84 files, 6.2M
```

My error on code run looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "igraphvizz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from igraph import *
  File "anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
ImportError: dlopen(anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155