# OSX rbenv install - Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully. Symlink belongs to pkg-config

Tags: macos, homebrew

I apologize if this question is a duplicate. I'm a noob when it comes to messing with brew.

I'm running this command:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

and in the output I'm getting this error:

```
==> Pouring pkg-config-0.29.2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/pkg-config
Target /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
is a symlink belonging to pkg-config. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink pkg-config

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite pkg-config

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run pkg-config
```

I haven't the foggiest idea what that means or the correct way to resolve it. I've read a few other bugs with similar issues, but I haven't found one that looked specifically like this.

Comment: I avoid using `brew` because they collect usage statistics (I think they use Google Analytics)... I'm not a fan of being observed. I recommend installing `rbenv` directly using `git`.

Comment: @Myst You can [opt-out](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Analytics.md#anonymous-aggregate-user-behaviour-analytics) from those analytics. They are however very helpful to maintainers in order to prioritize features & bug fixes based on usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: The 'brew link' step did not complete successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607155/error-the-brew-link-step-did-not-complete-successfully)

Comment: @Myst I went the git route (via these instructions http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/) and had no errors. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @bfontaine, I know about the opt-out option. I humbly disagree with this approach. opt-in is what I consider moral (since it requires an informed consent) while opt-out is what I consider sneaky (since uninformed or distracted users are participating without their consent).

Comment: @Todd, I'm happy you managed to to install `rbenv` without errors.

Comment: @Myst this has been extensively discussed and the consensus is: opt-in gives biased, unhelpful info. opt-out is sneaky if users are uninformed. That’s why users are informed are the first time they install or update Hombrew to the version with anonymous usage collection. Analytics data is *not* collected until they’ve been informed.

Comment: @bfontaine - I don't care about the consensus (nor do I understand how a consensus is decided). I'm only expressing my personal opinion. My opinion does not change because the consensus rejects it. My opinion will only change based on new experience and facts.

Comment: @Myst Sure. I’m just challenging your opinion because I think it’s misinformed (not uninformed and users are not participating without their consent).

Comment: @bfontaine I understand your position and I believe the consensus to be naive in it's assumption that people read pre/post installation messages. If a concise and targeted question isn't asked and a clear action isn't required, there's no point in reading this stuff... It would be better to assume that the percent of people reading these messages is similar to the percent of people reading the EULA on every iOS update before clicking "Agree"... which is probably very close to zero. And IMHO, these messages *should* be ignored. People are busy. Consent can't be assumed by "leaving a note".

Comment: @Myst thanks, that makes sense.