# Install two versions of SVN and switch between the two using `brew link & unlinked`

Tags: macos, svn, version-control, homebrew

With  svn 1.6. and 1.7, both installed. when I try to do `brew link subversion16` I get the following error `brew link subversion16 >> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/subversion16`Please advise.

MAC OX:

```
 $ which svn
  /usr/bin/svn



 $ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)
   compiled Jan 15 2014, 11:22:16

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/





$ brew link subversion16
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/subversion16
$ brew uninstall subversion16
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/subversion16
$ brew install subversion16
==> Downloading http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.6.23.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/subversion16-1.6.23.tar.bz2
==> Downloading patches
```

More info

```
brew info svn
subversion: stable 1.8.8 (bottled)
http://subversion.apache.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, autoconf ✘, automake ✘, libtool ✘, scons ✘
Required: sqlite ✘
==> Options

==> Caveats
svntools have been installed to:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/libexec
```

This answer didn't help:  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868133/cant-brew-link-an-unlinked-keg)

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted, it does not appear as though subversion16 has actually been installed yet. Brew has downloaded the tar file, but the lack of a keg in the cellar would indicate that is hasn't successfully completed the install. Make sure `brew install subversion16` runs all the way through.